# Design of C# form generator

Tags: c#, pdf

I am working on a software in C# for a company and I'd like some advice on the most efficient design. The company has many print-only forms that employees fill out. The software needs to maintain the original design of the form, but prompt and restrict the user so that the input is placed in the allocated fields. Right now I'm thinking of applying OCR recognition to the forms to convert them to .PDF, then generate (fill in the fields) of a new PDF.

- Does this seem like an efficient design?
- What is the best .PDF manipulation plugin for C# that would line up with this purpose

Any advice or critiques would be welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that using OCR is going to be accurate enough for this. In any case, I don't think that writing a piece of software is neccessary. [Adobe Acrobat](http://www.adobe.com/products/acrobat.html) should allow you to create a PDF from scanned images of your existing print forms, and you can set up fields for a suite of editable PDFs that the users just use as templates.